# Manipulating props using default in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Basically, I have very less edge cases where I need to change the value of props on init like so,

```
props : {
    columnName : String,
    setValue: {

        validator: function (value) {
            //enum edge cases
            let _value = value;
            if(value === 'YES' || value === 'ACTIVE'){
                value = 0;
            }
            else if(value === 'NO' || value === 'VOID'){
                value = 1;
            }
            console.log(_value);
            return _value;
        }
    }
},
```

Is this possible, I did try this but it is still sending the actual values instead of `0/1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to return 'value' rather than '_value'.
However, I believe this is a job for a computed property, rather than trying to manipulate the prop directly.

```
computed:{
  computedSetValue(){
    if(this.setValue === 'YES' || this.setValue === 'ACTIVE'){
      return 0
    }
    else if(this.setValue=== 'NO' || this.setValue=== 'VOID'){
      return 1
    } 
    return 0      
  }
}
```

Then, you may use `this.computedSetValue` as you do `this.setValue`

Comment: Great. Thanks for the quick help. I never knew this could be a possible way.